# Strings, integers, data types

Tags: string, integer, terminology

After several years of writing code for my own use, I'm trying to understand what does it really mean.

```
a = "Foo"
b = ""
c = 5
d = True
```

- `a` - string variable. `"Foo"` (with quotes) - string literal, i.e. an entity of the string data type.
- `b` - string variable. `""` - empty string.
- `c` - integer variable. `5` - integer literal, i.e. an entity of the integral data type.
- `d` - Boolean variable. `True` - Boolean value, i.e. an entity of the Boolean data type.

Questions:

- Is my understanding is correct?
- It seems that `5` is an integer literal, which is an entity of the integral data type. "Integer" and "integral": for what reason we use different words here?
- What is the "string" and "integer"?

  As I understand from Wikipedia, "string" and "integer" are not the same thing as string/integer literals or data types. In other words, there are 3 pairs or terms:

  - string literal, integer literal
  - string data type, integer data type
  - string, integer

Comment: The integral data type isn't a standard thing in any language I'm aware of

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, a literal value is any value which appears literally in code, e.g `"hello"` is a string literal, `123` is an integer literal, etc.  In contrast for example:

```c
int a = 5;
int b = 2;
int c = a + b;
```

`a` and `b` have literal values assigned to them, but `c` does not, it has a computed value assigned to it.

With any literal value we describe the literal value with it's data type ( as in the first sentence ), e.g. "string literal" or "integer literal".

Now a ***data type*** refers to how the computer, or the software running on the computer, interprets the binary value of some data.  For most kinds of data, the interpretation of the bytes is typically defined in a standard.  [`utf-8`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) for example is one way to interpret the *bytes* of a string's internal (binary) value.  Interestingly, the actual bytes of a string are treated as unsigned, 8-bit integers.  In `utf-8`, the values of those integers are combined in various ways to determine which glyph, or character, should appear on the screen when those values are encountered in the data. `utf-8` is a variable-byte-length encoding which can have between 1 and 4 bytes per character ( 8 to 32-bit ).

For numbers, particularly integers, implementations can vary, but most representations use four bytes with the most significant byte first in order, and the first bit of the first byte as the sign, with signed integers, or the first bit is simply the most significant bit for unsigned integers.  This is referred to as [**big-endian**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) ordering of bytes in a multi-byte integer.  There is also *little-endian* encoding, and integers can in principle use any number of bytes, but the most typically implemented are 1, 2, 4 and sometimes 8, where bit-wise you have 8, 16, 32 or 64, respectively. For integer sizes that are not of these sizes, typically requires a custom implementation.

For floating point numbers it gets a bit more tricky.  There is a common standard for floating point numbers called [IEEE-754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754) which describes how floats are encoded.  Likewise for floats, there are different sizes and variations, but primarily we use 16, 32, 64 and sometimes 24-bit in some mobile device graphics implementations.  There are also [extended precision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_precision) floats which use 40 or 80 bits.